# What strings do %{HTTP_HOST} and other mod_rewrite variables return?

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-headers

If I have a htaccess file that has `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}` in it, what *is* the `HTTP_HOST`? This is something I've been struggling to find out. To help me understand, could you tell me, in each example that someone might navigate to, what are the (values/responses (?) of) `HTTP_HOST`, `REQUEST_FILENAME` and `THE_REQUEST`? And what will a Rewrite rule actually rewrite?

1. `http://www.meow.co.uk`
2. `https://www.meow.co.uk`
3. `http://meow.co.uk`
4. `http://www.meow.co.uk/woof` ("woof" is a directory)
5. `http://www.meow.co.uk/woof/something.html`
6. `http://foo.bar.org.uk/meow` ("meow" is the same directory as meow.co.uk)
7. `http://foo.bar.org.uk/meow/woof/something` ("something" is the same html file as above)

It seems I can't log what is going on in my `htaccess` as I don't have access to the Apache config file.

---

**Update**

This question  was put on hold as being too broad. In trying to find out how to use mod_rewrite, I often come across quite specific questions and answers here and on SO, that might be close to what I want to achieve, but leave me with no greater understanding of what the mod_rewrite variables actually *are*. Sure, I can figure out what the regular expressions mean, but I don't understand exactly what string they are being executed against. If I knew that, I could probably figure out exactly what I need in my `.htaccess`, and I'm sure others could too.

So, rant over, let's look at examples 5 and 7 above.

What strings are the result of `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}`, `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}` and `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}` when you're navigating to

`http://www.meow.co.uk/woof/something.html` and

`http://foo.bar.org.uk/meow/woof/something`

And, assuming you have a `RewriteRule` after each `RewriteCond`, are those same strings what the rewrite rules operate on?

Comment: Is this really too broad? All I expect is a 7 item long list of results (and I suspect that some items will have the same answers)

Comment: HTTP_HOST is the hostname the user requests when accessing your site. and a RewriteRule can rewrite any URL. You might want to make your question more specific.

Comment: @Mike Thanks, from that I was able to look up [hostname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) on Wikipedia to find out that 'Hostnames are composed of series of labels concatenated with dots, as are all domain names. For example, "en.wikipedia.org" is a hostname'. Frustrating that my google searches wouldn't relinquish this sentence

Comment: The `HTTP_HOST` is `www.meow.co.uk`, `meow.co.uk` and `foo.bar.org.uk`. The `REQUEST_FILENAME` is the absolute filesystem filename of the resource being requested, so we don't know exactly what that would be just by looking at the URL. But for `http://www.meow.co.uk/woof/something.html` it could be something like `/home/user/public_html/woof/something.html`. `THE_REQUEST` is the original request header sent from the client eg. `GET /woof/something.html HTTP/1.1`.

Comment: @w3d Ah, and if you have `RewriteRule` under a `RewriteCond`, is the `RewrityeRule` operating on that same string?

Comment: The `RewriteRule` always works on the requested URL (or the _rewritten_ URL if you have multiple rules). The `RewriteCond` directive is simply a _condition_ that must be met before the `RewriteRule` will trigger. A bit like an IF statement... `IF (condition, condition, condition) then do the rewrite`.